# Saving an excel file on a windows shared folder using wine

Tags: wine, samba, playonlinux

I'm not sure if anyone can help with this particular scenario but here goes. I am currently running MS Office 2010 (Home and Business) on Ubuntu 13.10 using PlayOnLinux. I'm able to open excel files locally and save them locally just fine with no issues.

I can also open and view files on a windows shared folder just fine as well however, if I save the file, I get the following warning popup:

The document was saved successfully, but Excel cannot re-open it because of a sharing violation. Please close the document and try to open it again.

When I look at the file permissions on the shared drive now, they are changed from -rwxrwx--- to ---------- and no one is able to reopen the file.

One more thing, I mounted the drive in the fstab with the following options:cifs rw,nosetuids,noperm 0 0

This is probably a MS Office issue but I thought I'd ask here first to see if anyone else has experienced this or know how to fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I had the same problem and determined that it was because of a change I had made to my SAMBA configuration =.

I use a Mac to access files on a Linux server via SAMBA, and wanted to block the typical "dot" files that Mac creates (._something and .DS_STORE). So, I added a line to my smb.conf that would prevent those files from ever being created as follows:

veto files = /._*/.DS_Store/

When you open an Office file, it creates a temporary file in the location where you opened the file from, and that file starts with ._$

Since .*$ will be matched by .** the file will be disallowed and you're operating without a temporary file. Remove the "veto files" entry (or remove the ._* portion), restart SMB, and you'll be fine.